# Fastest way to divide plane into set of boards

Tags: modeling, mesh

What would be the fastest way to divide a plane into a set of boards?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to loop cut through the plane, and then somehow create spaces through those new edges.

[image]

Into this:

[image]

I'd prefer a method that I could use for ex. top faces of cubes, etc.

Comment: so what have you tried and why were you not glad? For example boolean would work fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply split the plane along the loopcuts.

1. Add some new loopcuts
2. *Select > All*
3. *Mesh > Split > Faces by Edges*

[image]